# Suprenum of set of lower semicontinuous functions is lower semicontinuous.

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

From Rudin, *Real and Complex Analysis*
We are given that a real valued function is lower semicontinuous if

{$x: f(x)> \alpha$}  is open for every real $\alpha$.

I'm thinking of proving the former as follows:

Take any family of lower semicontinuous functions

{$f_a$} for some indexed $a$

Then we have that 
{ $x: f_a (x)> \alpha$ } is open for all lower semicontinuous $f_a$.

Taking the sup of this set we know that it is still open.

Hence for $g=sup{f_a}$ we have that the set 
{x: g(x) > $\alpha$} must also be open...

I would like to know if there is a way to formalize this sketch?

I've seen other proofs of this statement but they seem to follow from a few more facts on lower semicontinuous functions, which are not immediately presented in this book.

Comment: what's "the former"???

Comment: The statement in the title..

Answer (score 1):

I'm a bit confused what you're asking. It seems all you need to do is show that if $\{x : f_a(x) > \alpha\}$ is open for each $\alpha$, then $\{x : \sup_a f_a(x) > \alpha\}$ is open. But this is easy. If $\sup_a f_a(x) > \alpha$, then $f_a(x) > \alpha$ for some $a$ and so by assumption, there's some neighborhood around $x$ for which $f_a > \alpha$, and then on this neighborhood, $\sup_a f_a > \alpha$, as desired.

Answer (score 1):

$\{x:\sup_a f_a(x)>\alpha \}=\cup_a \{x:f_a(x)>\alpha \}$ and union of open sets is open.

Comment: Actually that was one of my first thoughts.. how do we know it's certain that it's a union?

Comment: Just show that each side is contained in the other.  If a number is less than the supremum of certain numbers then it must be less than one of those numbers; this shows that LHS is contained in RHS. To show that RHS is contained in LHS just observe that each of the sets $\{x:f_a(x)>\alpha \}$ is contained in  LHS.